# How to do exploratory analysis on very large dataset?

Tags: large-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have very large dataset stored in Google Cloud BigQuery.

(the system dumps a table everyday. A table has approximately 25GB of size, and I have 2 months data = 60 tables = 60x25 GB)

It is quite painful to conduct exploratory analysis on such a large dataset. I'd like to know if there are some good method or guideline I can follow for exploratory analysis?

Comment: ask for a lot of time to do your work! some additional info - what makes it large data (large #columns, large #rows). Is it a "simple" dataset that you are capturing repeatedly over time (ie sec, min, hours a new copy is made)...etc

Comment: @probabilityislogic Thanks for the comment. Here is some additional info: each table has about 70 columns, the row# is pretty large. The system is a web analytics system, which is basically recording user clicks on my website. And one table is a summarize of all user clicks happened in this day.

Comment: You would probably get answers, if you could describe what you want to find with your analysis.